# how to implement drag and drop widgets using angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Is there any way by which i can implement draggable widgets in a page using angular js. The requirememt is that when i drag and drop one widget to a new place, the other widgets should reposition automatically similar to the UI offered by Google Keep app.?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at project [UI-Sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)

It provides bindings for the jqueryUI sortable and suited my needs pretty well.